# Is there a way to combine existentials with typeclasses?

Tags: scala, typeclass, existential-type

### The question

I'm using spray, and I'm trying to express the concept of a heterogeneous JSON array -- that is, an array in which everything is a member of `JsonFormat`.  For example, the scala value might look like this:

```
case class Dog(name: String, age: Int)

// not sure how to express this type
val json: [???] = List(3, "abc", List(), Dog("Rover", 3))
```

and the corresponding JSON would look like this:

```
[3, "abc", {"qrs": 4}, [], {"name": "Rover", "age": 3}]
```

I've tagged the question "existentials" and "typeclasses" because I'm guessing that's what the solution will involve (I'd be happy to change that if that's wrong).  I have figured out a workaround already, so the purpose of this post is really to figure out how to express this in the Scala type system.

---

### What I've tried:

- this forces all of the elements to be of the same type, whereas I'm trying to express a heterogeneous list:

  ```
  case class MyJson1[T](items: List[T])

  object JsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit def dogFormat = jsonFormat2(Dog)
    implicit def format[T : JsonFormat] = jsonFormat1(MyJson1[T])
  }
  ```
- `Any` doesn't allow the type system to prove that the values will be members of `JsonFormat`:

  ```
  case class MyJson2(items: List[Any])

  object JsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit def dogFormat = jsonFormat2(Dog)
    implicit val format = jsonFormat1(MyJson2)
  }
  ```
- `_` (existential) has the same problem: the compiler can't prove that the items are members of `JsonFormat`:

  ```
  case class MyJson3(items: List[_])

  object JsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit def dogFormat = jsonFormat2(Dog)
    implicit val format = jsonFormat1(MyJson3)
  }
  ```
- okay, this was just a wild guess and doesn't work:

  ```
  case class MyJson4[T](items: List[T])

  object JsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
    implicit def dogFormat = jsonFormat2(Dog)
    implicit def format[C <: JsonFormat[T] forSome { type T}] = jsonFormat1(MyJson4[C])
  }
  ```

Comment: I don't think it is possible the way you have it. Can't have a list of values of different types (so list of Any here) and say that each of them has instance of JsonFormat because this list can contain anything, and you don't want it in compile time. You either need JsonFormat[Any] which is as bad. List[Any] is bad as well. Solution probably involves HLists.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is to create a "wrapper" that holds a *value* and the typeclass *instance*.

```
class Wrapper[T](val value: T, val format: JsonFormat[T])
object Wrapper {
  def apply[T](value: T)(implicit format: JsonFormat[T]) = new Wrapper(value, format)
}

val json: List[Wrapper[_]] = List(Wrapper(3), Wrapper("abc"), Wrapper(Dog("Rover", 3))

// or use an implicit conversion to wrapper
implicit def wrapValue[T: JsonFormat](value: T) = Wrapper(value)
// note that you *must* explicitly state the list type in order for the conversion to apply
val json: List[Wrapper[_]] = List(3, "abc", Dog("Rover", 3))
```

You may run into trouble when doing something like:

```
for(wrapper <- json) yield {
  wrapper.format.doWhateverJsonFormatDoes(wrapper.value) // error
}
```

There'd be some kind of "type mismatch" error, but you can get around that by defining a "wrapper" for the typeclass method, in the `Wrapper` class:

```
class Wrapper[T](val value: T, val format: JsonFormat[T]){
  def doWhateverJsonFormatDoes = format.doWhateverJsonFormatDoes(value)
}

for(wrapper <- json) yield wrapper.doWhateverJsonFormatDoes
```